# How can I tell an event is not forged?

Tags: events, event-handling

Say you have a service in your system that listens to Ethereum events and let's imagine it does some pre-processing to broadcast only a subset of events to the rest of the system.

When other parts of the system receive the broadcasted/relayed events, can they verify the event is genuine and was actually created by the Ethereum mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The transaction receipt has a record of the events generated during the execution, and the block contains the root of the patricia trie of every transaction receipt in the block. A cryptographic proof can be generated and validated by the API consumers.